# Send Arabic Text to Web Service

Tags: vba, excel, utf-8

Okay, I'm confused.  My problem is that I want to send the contents of my Excel spreadsheet to a HTTP POST web service, in UTF8 encoding - i.e I want to support Arabic text.

I can iterate through the cells of a spreadsheet writing to a stream:

```
Dim fsT 'As New Stream
Set fsT = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
fsT.Type = 2'Specify stream type - we want To save text/string data.
fsT.Charset = "utf-8" 'Specify charset For the source text data.
fsT.Open 'Open the stream And write binary data To the object
```

I can if I wish save this to a file, my Arabic text is preserved.

When I send this to my service, I send it as a binary, this is possibly my downfall.

```
'Change stream type To binary
 fsT.Position = 0
 fsT.Type = adTypeBinary
```

Followed by

```
 Set oHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")
 Call oHttp.Open("POST", pHtml, False)
 oHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/text"
 oHttp.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
 Call oHttp.send(fsT.Read)
```

However I have also tried to send as text, without changing the stream type

```
Call oHttp.send(fsT.ReadText)
```

In both cases the Arabic text that is received on my server is simply a series of question marks ??? ??? ??? etc.  Which incidentally is what I get on the VBA if I look at the output of sft.ReadText.

So - I can output to a file fine, but not anything else without loosing my text.

My VBA is not great, and I'm sure I'm about to be told how stupid I am, but at the risk of that, can anyone help - I have been trying many permutations of things, and I just can't get the text sent over.

Comment: can you try changing "Content-Type", "application/text" to "Content-Type", "text/html"

Comment: The main question is what is the web service expecting from this POST request? Is it really expecting simply byte data within the POST body? How is the web service normally getting its data? If it gets it normally from an HTML Form, then it will expect application/x-www-form-urlencoded.

Comment: I have tried text/html - same problem.  The web service reads from an InputStream, my understanding is this reads from a stream of bytes.  It does not expect a HTML form.  To me the problem is on the VBA side, if I go to the immediate window and print the contents of fsT.ReadText then this prints the text with question marks - not the Arabic text - so I think it is what is being sent, rather then how it is being received.

Comment: The immediate window can't show Unicode. So this is not a hint. Again: How is the web service normally get its data if it not get them from VBA? And where you see the question marks after the POST request?

Comment: Shot in the dark: Don't change the stream type to binary but let it be 2 (adTypeText). Then use `"Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8"` and `oHttp.send(fsT.ReadText)`. Or set the stream type to 1 (adTypeBinary) using `fsT.Type = 1` - maybe adTypeBinary is not what you thought since you are using late binding. Then use `"Content-Type", "application/octet-stream"` and `oHttp.send(fsT.Read)`.

Comment: Hi - Thanks for all your replies, sorry I've only just got back to this.  I have tired on the server (Java) to read the stream of data directly from the request (HttpServletRequest.getInputStream()) and print it out, I get this: "Ù…Ø±Ø­Ø¨Ø§ Ø¨Ø§Ù„Ø¹Ø§Ù„Ù…"  It does not make any difference what I set the content type to on the header.  If I createa a Java UTF-8 InputStreamReader (new InputStreamReader(request.getInputStream(), "UTF-8") and print out the text I get this: "????? ???????"

Comment: As a further test, I have created the VBA stream as a binary stream, written the arabic text directly to the stream as a bytearray, and then sent to the server - I get a different set of funny characters which I can not paste here, changing the encoding on the HTTP headers still has no effect.  I will continue to investigate

Comment: @Agent96: See my answer. It should work. You mentioned: "read the stream of data directly from the request (HttpServletRequest.getInputStream()) and print it out". Where and how you print it out? Also "(new InputStreamReader(request.getInputStream(), "UTF-8") and print out the text". Where and how you print out the text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your answer I get a suspicion.

What you are doing is the following:

You write the pure unencoded Unicode bytes in the binary  `ADODB.Stream`. Then with concatenating `"" & fsT.Read` you are creating a Unicode String. As in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms763706%28v=vs.85%29.aspx mentioned: "If the input type is a BSTR, the response is always encoded as UTF-8." So the `IXMLHTTPRequest` will encode this string to UTF-8.

The text `ADODB.Stream` with `.Charset = "utf-8"` will also have an Unicode String in it's `.ReadText`. But after changing to binary, it will have a UTF-8 BOM (EFBBBF) at the beginning of it's `.Read`. This BOM is what is confusing your webservice.

Please try if

```
 Set fsT = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
 fsT.Charset = "UTF-8"
 fsT.Type = 2

 fsT.Open

 For Each cell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells
  fsT.WriteText cell.Value
 Next

 fsT.Position = 0

 Set oHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")
 oHttp.Open "POST", pHtml, False
 oHttp.send "" & fsT.ReadText
```

will also work. If so, then this is the cleaner solution in my opinion.

Comment: Yes - it worked!  Thanks for this, it is cleaner, and thanks for the explanation of what is actually happening under the covers.

Comment: Thats fine. Good to know this. Hint: If the `ADODB.Stream` is only used to create the Unicode string for the HTTP-POST, then the `.Charset = "UTF-8"` is not needed. It is only needed if the stream shall also be saved in a UTF-8 encoded file. The charset of a `ADODB.Stream` defaults to Unicode, which is needed for the string. And in my opinion it should also work with `oHttp.send fsT.ReadText` without the concatenation, since `.ReadText` returns a string already.

Comment: Yes, in fact it does work without the empty string concatenation, as expected, and without utf-8 as the Charset.  I'm starting to wonder why I had so many problems, and I think it was my own fault as my Java console was not set to output UTF-8 characters for a lot of my early tests. So all of my initial trials were giving me false information.

Answer (score 1):

If both sites (server and client) talking the same language (in this case HTTP) and the server really expects simply UTF-8 encoded bytes in the POST request body, then it should work.

Of course this is a assertion. But i will prove it.

So i have the following simple Java server running:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

class SimplestServerPOST extends Thread {

 private ServerSocket srvSock = null;
 private Socket sock = null;
 private BufferedInputStream bin = null;
 private DataOutputStream out = null;
 private int contentLength = 0;     
 private int c = 0;     

 SimplestServerPOST(int port, int timeout) {

  super();

  try {
   System.out.println("Server start.");
   srvSock = new ServerSocket(port, 5);
   srvSock.setSoTimeout(timeout);
   start();
  } catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }

 public void run() {
  System.out.println("Server run.");

  while (true) {
   try {
    sock = srvSock.accept();
//Begin request-handling
    try {
     StringBuffer headerLine = new StringBuffer("");
     bin = new BufferedInputStream(sock.getInputStream());
     out = new DataOutputStream(sock.getOutputStream());

     while ((c = bin.read()) >= 0) {
      if ((c == 10) || (c == 13)) { //if there is a linebreak, then the line ends
       if (c == 13) { //handle CRLF linebreak
        bin.mark(1);
        if (bin.read() != 10) bin.reset();
       }

       if (headerLine.length() == 0) break; //the whole header section ends if the first empty line occurs
       //get the content-length header
       if (headerLine.toString().toLowerCase().startsWith("content-length")) {
        contentLength = Integer.parseInt(headerLine.toString().split(" ")[1]);
       }

       System.out.println(headerLine.toString());

       headerLine.delete(0, headerLine.length()); //new headerline
      } else {
       headerLine.append((char)c); //get one byte for headerline
      }
     }

     byte[] buffer = new byte[contentLength];
     bin.read(buffer);

     System.out.println(new String(buffer, "UTF-8"));

     FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("POSTContent.txt");
     fw.write(new String(buffer, "UTF-8"));
     fw.close();

     out.writeBytes("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n");
     out.writeBytes("Connection: close\r\n");
     out.writeBytes("\r\n");
     out.close();
    } catch(Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
    }
//End request-handling
    sock.close();
   } catch (InterruptedIOException e) {
    try {
     int sSTo = srvSock.getSoTimeout();
     // This is only to understand the functionality.
     //System.out.println("No requests for " + sSTo + "ms.");
    } catch (Exception et) {
     et.printStackTrace();
    }
   } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
  }
 }

 protected void finalize() {
  if (srvSock != null) {
   try {
    srvSock.close();
   } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
   srvSock = null;
  }
 }
}

class SimplestServerPOSTMain {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  SimplestServerPOST srv = new SimplestServerPOST(2000, 1000);
 }
}
```

And i send a POST request to this server from the following VBA:

```
Sub test()

 Set oADOStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
 oADOStream.Type = 2
 oADOStream.Charset = "utf-8"
 oADOStream.Open

 oADOStream.WriteText "Test umlauts: äöü", 1
 oADOStream.WriteText "Test euro sign: €", 1
 oADOStream.WriteText "Test arabic: " & ChrW(1587) & "  " & ChrW(1588) & "  " & ChrW(1589) & "  " & ChrW(1590), 1

 oADOStream.Position = 0

 Set oWinHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")
 oWinHTTP.Open "POST", "http://192.168.0.10:2000", False

 'oWinHTTP.Send oADOStream.ReadText

 oADOStream.Type = 1
 oWinHTTP.Send oADOStream.Read

End Sub
```

The result is:

[image]

This console is a Linux console. A Windows console maybe will not be able to display the characters properly. But the file POSTContent.txt should contain them properly.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, this is exactly how I thought it should work, and was what I had origianally done.  But for whatever reason I could not get this to work.  I have posted an answer which solves the problem for me - I don't exactly know why it works, but it does.

Answer (score 1):

Ok - thanks for all your help.  I do not know why but none of the suggestions worked. I have however found a solution which works for me.  It is:

1. Create a Binary Stream,
2. Write the Cell values from Excel to a ByteArray - and write the byte array to the stream
3. Send the stream - importantly - concatenated with a blank string.

An example of what I have done follows:

```
Dim fsT 'As New Stream
Set fsT = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
fsT.Type = adTypeBinary 'Specify stream type - we want To save text/string data.

Dim b() As Byte
For Each cell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells
  b = cell.Value
  fsT.Write b
Next

fsT.Position = 0
Call oHttp.Open("POST", pHtml, False)
oHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/text;charset=UTF-8"
Call oHttp.send("" & fsT.Read)
```

Note the last line, if I remove the concatenation of the String, it does not come to the server as Arabic.

I think perhaps the reason the other answer to this question did not work, is the way I am getting the text (cell.Value) rather then directly writing UniCode to the stream.